# How do I best check if "anything has changed" in a given dir tree in PHP? (My old method appears to have broken.)

Tags: php, windows, filesystems, command-line-interface

For a long time, I have had a function which is able to check whether an entire directory tree has "changed" or not.

By "changed", I mean anything such as a file anywhere inside the dir tree has been deleted, a file has been added, a file has been renamed, a file has been touched/written to/modified, etc. Or the same for any sub-dirs, obviously. Basically, "any kind of change" besides simply accessing/reading the files.

It works like this:

1. Run clearstatcache();
2. Fetch all sub-dirs (and their sub-dirs) from the base dir.
3. Loop through them one by one and run filemtime($the_path . '/.') on each one and record the timestamps.
4. If the next time the timestamp differs for any of them, return `true`.
5. If none of them differs, return `false`.

Simple enough. Worked for ages. Now suddenly has broken. It only reacts on things being deleted/added, but not if a file is modified!

I recently upgraded from Windows 10 2004 to 2009. Maybe that was it? Not that it helps even if I know that this is the reason. I run PHP 8.0.13, and previously 8.0.12, so it is probably not PHP's fault. I always use the same file system (NTFS). But I want this to be a universal solution anyway; that's why I use PHP in the first place.

What can I do? Do I really need to manually loop through all the *individual files* as well now? And storing all their timestamps... ugh. Not gonna be nice for performance. I don't even understand why I had to check per-subdir in the first place. It should obviously support just checking the base dir.

Comment: @ColoradoAkpan It's not feasible for me to jump back and forth between PHP versions, but even if that's it, what does it help me? I can't stay on some old version anyway. And I have no idea what you mean by "check the PHP version you currently running", since I already mentioned exactly which one. And what do you mean by "debugging"? It throws no error.

Comment: @ColoradoAkpan Of course I have error logging on... There are no errors.

Comment: @ColoradoAkpan I'm not even convinced that you've read my question.

Comment: What command are you using to check the file timestamp ? (filemtime ??)

Comment: @KenLee See point 3. `filemtime($the_path . '/.')` That's the dir. Not individual files. Please read...

Comment: For a windows sytem, Please use filectime with filemtime (or even use fileatime, depending on your needs) . For details please refer to this [official_documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Comment: @KenLee I don't understand your comment. Why would filectime (creation time) be relevant?

Comment: filectime is inode change time

Comment: Its time u dive in the `SplFileInfo` section of PHP documentation. There is a function for Last Access, Creation and modified time

Comment: Not an answer to the question but for this kind of need you may check `Watchman` utility from Facebook: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/